# (Struct *) Initialization using attribute value name?

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, memset

I have defined this struct:

```
typedef struct WHEATHER_STRUCT
{
   unsigned char packetID[1];
   unsigned char packetSize[2];
   unsigned char subPacketID[1];
   unsigned char subPacketOffset[2];
   ...
} wheather_struct;
```

How can I initialize this struct (using constructor or new) accessing by an attribute name? For example:

```
wheather_struct.packetID = 1;
```

> Finally

I tried this solution and it works for me, but do you think it is a good choice?

```
WHEATHER_STRUCT * wheather_struct = new WHEATHER_STRUCT();
*weather_struct->packetID = '1';
```

And for a float attribute:

```
wheather_struct->floatAttribute= 111.111
```

Comment: Give the struct a proper constructor (or use in-class initializers for the default values) and stop using `malloc` in C++.

Comment: "_How can I initialize this struct using malloc and update this value accessing to an attribute name?_" Why do you even use `malloc`? What's wrong with using constructors, and `new`?

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` in a C++ program?  If any of those members of `WEATHER_STRUCT` change to non-POD types, that `malloc` call will not create the object and you now have to hunt down a hard-to-find bug.

Comment: Ok, I can not use new because the stuct is so long. But this I used malloc, but now I know that is not a good choise. Should I use constructor for this example?

Comment: *Ok, I can not use new because the stuct is so long.* -- ????????  Do you know what `new` does?

Comment: Can you give me a little example please? I thank that initialize a big struct using new was a bad choise.

Comment: @JoseJimRin *I thank that initialize a big struct using new was a bad choise*  -- Again, Huh?  Why did you think `malloc` was going to be any different (right now) than `new`?  Where are you getting this (poor) advice from?

Comment: I do not know Paul, by this I posted this question :S

Comment: Well, you should know what `new` does before making assumptions as to what it does.  The answers below show how to ditch `malloc` and just use `new` to create the object, and also how not to use `new` at all and just create the object outright.  Using `C` constructs in a C++ program is a dangerous game if you do not know what you're doing.

Comment: Why is your array `packetID` only `1` element long?

Comment: Because I need to use only 1 byte to send this information in a socket. (Is the Header)

Comment: You do know that there are fixed with integer types in C++! https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Comment: Yes but if I uses unsigned char i do not need to use <cstdint> library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you can use `new` to allocate and initialize:

```
wheather_struct *p = new wheather_struct();
```

Note the parenthesis at the end - this is [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) - fills members of built-in types with 0.

And then:

```
p->packetID[0] = 1;
```

Comment: If I use this solution compiler says me that "expression must be an L-value modifiable"

Comment: @JoseJimRin On which line?

Comment: It seems like i need to write *p -> packetID = '1', this works for me.

Comment: @JoseJimRin `p->packetID[0] = 1;`

Comment: OK, thanks, But if I have 2 bytes to represent an information. And I need to put a value 300. *p -> packetID = '300'; Is the correct option?

Comment: @JoseJimRin `packetID` is 1 byte, can contain values in range [0, 255].

Comment: Yes sorry, if I have 2 bytes to represent values. For example, packetSize. packetSize = '300'; Is the correct option? @MaximEgorushkin

Comment: @JoseJimRin What encoding does your protocol use?

Answer (score 1):

You can add initializers `{}` to your arrays to initialize them to zeros like this:

```
struct wheather_struct // no need for typedef in C++
{
   unsigned char packetID[1]{};
   unsigned char packetSize[2]{};
   unsigned char subPacketID[1]{};
   unsigned char subPacketOffset[2]{};
};
```

Then use `new` to dynamically create an object:

```
auto w = new weather_struct;

w->packetID[0] = 'A';
```

Don't forget to *delete* it later:

```
delete w;
```

But (much better) use a smart pointer:

```
auto w = std::make_unique<weather_struct>(); // will delete itself

w->packetID[0] = 'A';

// no need to delete it
```

Or (even better) just use it as a value object (not always possible):

```
weather_struct w; 

w.packetID[0] = 'A';
```

Comment: Compiler do not let me to put brackets {} in the struct definition.

Comment: @JoseJimRin You probably need to set the `C` version on your compiler to `C++11` or above. What compiler are you using?

Comment: Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.XX.YYYYY.ZZ for 80x86

Comment: @JoseJimRin I think you can use `/std:c++11` or `/std:c++latest` on the command line.